# Are there any issues using amazonaws.com uri for Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Assume that I have created a Cloudfront distribution for a S3 bucket.

Does it matter if you use the aws uri such as bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com verses using d2a3tewy8xuw6.cloudfront.net? Are there any issues using amazonaws.com uri for Cloudfront?

I'm currently using a cname in-front of my bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com uri so the change it pretty easy.

Answer (score 4):

It does matter. Using `bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com` means you are referencing the S3 storage direct and *not* CloudFront. The requests will be served from wherever the S3 servers are (America, I assume) instead of an edge location closer to the user. Obviously this means you don't get the speed benefits; I believe S3 bandwidth is also more expensive than CF.

You can use a CNAME in front of the S3 bucket if you like, but again that's not using CloudFront so if you want to use it the CNAME should point to `d2a3tewy8xuw6.cloudfront.net` instead.